# How to change state of global variable in components? (Vue 3)

Tags: vue.js, state-management

I am fairly new to Vue3 and web dev in general. my practice setup is with Vue3 and express.

I'm thinking using a global properties like `app.config.globalProperties.$isAuthenticated` and make it toggle between true and false depending on an axios call to server. Everythin works fine, except I just cannot change its state in any component by `this.isAuthenticated` = true or false.

Things i tried, `this.$isAuthnticated`, use `ref` or `reactive` in app.js to delcare it in the first place. none of them works for me. In the end i want a global variable to react to server response.

could anyone point me a right direction here? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the exact code how you define and use the $isAuthenticated globalProperty?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue and tried to find something that resolves the issue.

I found [this](https://dev.to/manuelojeda/learn-to-create-your-custom-global-state-management-with-vue-3-11am) article about state managment. With it you can create states in the App component while using the variables in any component.

Comment: I'm also still looking for a great solution, since I gave up my idea with a feature. I wan't to avoid an emit and props hell